# .NetCore + Angular + Azure: Deployment

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment, post-build-event

I created a Web Api Asp.Net Core Project in *server* folder and an Angular-Cli Project in *client* folder.

#### In local:

- I launch the WebAPI with *IIS Express* and my angular project with

  ```
  ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json*.
  ```
- In my Angular App, in *environments/environment.ts*, to be able to get the ApiUrl using *environment.apiUrl* (proxy doesnt work for websocket used with SignalR), I added a new parameter:

  ```
  apiUrl: "http://localhost:49402/"
  ```
- File structure:

[image: File Structure of my project]

My project is available on git too:
https://github.com/ranouf/AspNetCore-SignalR/

#### On Azure:

- I created a new WebApp,
- I configured the *deployment options*, each time *master* is modified, the Web App is deployed which works well for my WebApi.

#### Problem:

**How to deploy my Angular App in the Web App on Azure?**

#### My thinking:

I added a post build command which will build my angular app in the *wwwroot* folder only in release mode. This solution works in local but **doesnt work on Azure**:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
<PostBuildEvent>
  cd "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/../../client"
  npm install
  npm run build
</PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And in startup.cs, I added

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

#### Constraint:

I have to separate my 2 projects in Local, I can't use the webpack microsoft angular template.

Thanks for your help.
Cedric

---

#### Edit

So I m still working on it.

It s really hard to debug and understand what s happening on Azure Portal. The log on Deployment doesnt give the build output.

[image]

My new pre build command is :

```
echo "$(ProjectDir)..\..\client"
cd $(ProjectDir)..\..\client
echo "npm install"
npm install
echo "ng build"
ng build --env=prod --prod --output-path=$(ProjectDir)
```

But still, nothing is copied in the server folder ...

Please, can you share your thinking? How can I deploy my angular App using Deployment Option in Azure portal?

---

#### Edit 2

So, I saw no solution online, and no one answer here too, so what I want to do first seems to not be possible.

I try something else, the kudu deployment script. You need to add two file:

- .deployment with this lines inside:

  ```
  [config]
  command = deploy.cmd
  ```
- deploy.cmd:

  ```
  @if "%SCM_TRACE_LEVEL%" NEQ "4" @echo off

  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  :: Setup
  :: -----
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

  IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE (
    SET DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE=%ARTIFACTS%\repository
  )

  IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_TARGET (
    SET DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=%ARTIFACTS%\wwwroot
  )

  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  :: Deployment
  :: ----------
  echo Source: %DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%...
  echo Deployment: in %DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%...

  echo Server off
  touch %DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\App_Offline.htm

  pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\src\client"
  echo npm install --production
  call :ExecuteCmd npm install --production
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

  echo Deploy client
  call :ExecuteCmd npm run build-azure
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  popd

  echo Deploy API
  call :ExecuteCmd dotnet publish src\server\AspNetCore-SignalR.Api\ -o %DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  :: End
  :: ---
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

  goto end

  :: Execute command routine that will echo out when error
  :ExecuteCmd
  setlocal
  set _CMD_=%*
  call %_CMD_%
  if "%ERRORLEVEL%" NEQ "0" echo Failed exitCode=%ERRORLEVEL%, command=%_CMD_%
  exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

  :error
  endlocal
  echo An error has occurred during web site deployment.
  call :exitSetErrorLevel
  call :exitFromFunction 2>nul

  :exitSetErrorLevel
  exit /b 1

  :exitFromFunction
  ()

  :end
  endlocal
  echo Finished successfully.
  ```

There is 2 good points:

- the deployment succeded
- all the files (DotNet Core publish + Angular publish) are in wwwroot

There is 1 BIG problem:

- I can access to the API using swagger (www.website.com/swagger) but the angular App is not available (error 404 on www.webiste.com)
- If I remove the web.config, the Angular App is now available, but not swagger or the API anymore.

How to make understand to the web.config that I want both work Angular App and Swagger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! It was hard, I tried many things even the Kudu Deploy script:

- https://github.com/ranouf/AspNetCore-SignalR/blob/0a648617eafd77be6c8e057160c2a66f2ee266b8/.deployment.old
- https://github.com/ranouf/AspNetCore-SignalR/blob/0a648617eafd77be6c8e057160c2a66f2ee266b8/deploy.cmd.old2

(for those who could be interested to see how to do that).

But finally, I choose the (maybe) easiest solution, the PreBuildEvent command.

In my csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
  <PreBuildEvent>
    cd "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/../../client"
    npm install
  </PreBuildEvent>
  <PostBuildEvent>
    cd "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/../../client"
    npm run build-azure
  </PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In Package.json:

```
"build": "ng build --env=prod --prod --output-path=../server/AspNetCore-SignalR.Api/wwwroot/",
"build-azure": "ng build --env=prod --prod --output-path=D:/home/site/wwwroot/wwwroot/",
```

The main things to know is when you want to deploy an Angular App, you need to do it in wwwroot folder. 
In Azure, the .Net app is deployed in D:/home/site/wwwroot/. My mistake was to think that I have to deploy my angular app there too. The good thing to do is to deploy it in D:/home/site/wwwroot/wwwroot.

I hope, my work will help people too. If you have any recommendations to improve the process and reinforce the security, please let met know.